# Get the view of Fullcalendar before dayRender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am working working on a asp.net MVC project which requires to color every holiday. The holiday information is stored in database. Now I implement this by using ajax in the `dayRender` event of Fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    dayRender: function(date, cell)
    {
         $.ajax({
             async: false,
             cache: false,
             global: false,
             url: "[path]/IsHoliday",
             type: "POST",
             data: {sDate: date.format("yyyy/mm/dd")},
             dataType: "text",
             success: function(val){
                  if(val == "true"){
                      cell.css("background-color", "cyan")
                  }
             }
         })
    } 
});
```

By this mean, the holiday of the calendar can be colored.
**BUT** the problem is that they day cells can't be colored immediately when the page loads. Some Cells might be colored **3s** after the page-load. Is there a **BETTER** way toe implement this functionality in FullCalendar whith **NO DELAY**?

*p.s. My thought is that before the `dayRender` event, I can **somehow** find the `view` of the calendar, get the holiday information through it, then use the holiday information in `dayRender` event. But **HOW** can i get 'view' before `dayRender`?*

Comment: You don't need views or dayRender, or day cells for this. There is a much simpler solution which uses the calendar more in the way it's intended to be - see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389008/5947043) below

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the holidays as an [event source](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-source-object) and set all the events in that source to be rendered as [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/background-events) so that they colour the whole day.

For example, a background event object you could send from your server (in JSON format) representing a holiday on 6th December 2019 and coloured cyan would look something like this:

```
{
  start: "2019-12-06",
  end: "2019-12-06",
  allDay: true,
  rendering: "background",
  color: "#00FFFF"
}
```

However, if you want all events in a source to be rendered in the background and coloured the same way you can set that property on the event source in the fullCalendar config, rather than sending it from the server:

```
{
  url: "/Calendar/Holidays",
  rendering: "background",
  color: "#00FFFF"
}
```

And then the JSON for an individual event (returned from the URL) could be shortened to:

```
{
  start: "2019-12-06",
  end: "2019-12-06",
  allDay: true,
}
```

So putting it together you could configure the calendar something like this. Remove the `events` property (assuming you have one) and replace it with `eventSources`, defined in this kind of way:

```
eventSources: [
  // holidays
  {
    url: "/Calendar/Holidays",
    rendering: "background",
    color: "#00FFFF"
  },
  //other events
  {
    url: "/Calendar/Events",
  }
]
```

Here's a live demo (using hard-coded events instead of URL sources, just for demo purposes): http://jsfiddle.net/5qtk8mxf/

N.B. Your `Calendar/Holidays` action on the server should return a JSON array containing all holidays within the current time period (as specified by the `start` and `end` GET parameters which fullCalendar [https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed](automatically appends to the AJAX request it generates), in the exact same way that the `Calendar/Events` action should. This ensures you just get a list of relevant holidays and events to be displayed on the calendar, rather than a list of every holiday and events which has ever (or will ever) occur, which would cause an unnecessary amount of data transfer and processing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your method and that works. But there are some other problems along with that: What I want render is the cell's background, while your method renders the background of the event in the cell. This is leads to that their color look different although I use cyan in both cases, and the functions I coded for changing the color of cell when clicking does not work anymore, so is it possible to fix the new problems or take some other way to approach it?

Comment: My idea on the problem is that there should be some "event" (like dayRender, viewRender) prior to the event 'dayRender'.  Then in the 'function' of this event, I can get 'start' and 'end' from 'view' object. With that i can get the holidays of current month view before 'dayRender' with one ajax call. **But how can I find the events before 'dayRender'?**

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/viewRender might help you, it'll give you info about the current view. As to whether it runs before dayRender - I expect so, but you can test it easily - just enable both handlers and add a console log command inside each callback, and see which one happens first. Or you could study the source code of fullCalendar v3.

Comment: However, I think we can resolve your other problems without needing viewRender. The colour change issue is because of opacity. Just add `.fc-bgevent {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}` to your CSS and it fixes it - see http://jsfiddle.net/0znpj7Ls/ (If you inspect the highlighted day using your browser's Developer Tools you would see the opacity rule in the computed styles of the element, so this rule just overrides the one applied by fullCalendar)

Comment: "the functions I coded for changing the color of cell when clicking does not work anymore"...if you were using dayClick for this, then just eventClick instead. You can easily see if the event is a holiday / background event or not after it's been clicked, and then decide what to do. I can't see that being a big issue.

Comment: For [comment 1], `viewRender` doesn't work, because it happens after `daRender`. I tried to search `pulicklyTrigger`, which is used to generate handlers, in the fullcalendar.js, but didn't find an option likely to workd. I am not sure whether such method could work.

Comment: dFor [comment 2&3], the displayed color is right with your css code, thanks for that. [`eventClicked` will not be triggered for `EventSources`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventClick), I can toggle the color with class `fc-bgevent` in a `dayClick` callback function, but that would change  colors of all cells. Is that possible to just change the  background-color of the day clicked?

Comment: "eventClicked will not be triggered for EventSources,"...that's not true. But maybe you mean it's not triggered for background events? That could be an issue, indeed, I had forgotten about that sorry.

Comment: "Is that possible to just change the background-color of the day clicked"...of course. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayClick says "Within the callback function, `this` is set to the <td> of the clicked day." So `this.css("background-color", "#00FFFF");` will do the job. http://jsfiddle.net/6tur9k0v/ . Although this seems to be a different feature than your original requirement?

Comment: Your method in your last comment can paint a blank cell to cyan, but it can't remove the event background-color with code `cell.css("background-color", "")` ,   which can blank a cell in my original functions. But I have camp up another way to implement my desired function based your answer. You can take a look if interested.

Answer (score 1):

Thank @ADyson for introducing a brilliant method and giving a lot of helpful suggestions, yet his answer still doesn't solve my problem due to conflicts with my other functions. However, based on his suggestions, I finally worked out a method to implement described function without conflict. The trick is **fetching the holidays in current month view in `eventSource`**. `eventSource` 'happens' before `dayRender` so that I can get holiday information with one `ajax` and render the holiday cells, not very elegant, but much better that my original solution.
My code is like this:

```
eventSources: [{
  url: [path]/Holidays  //Holidays return List<HOLIDAY> JSON feed
  type: 'POST'
  data: function(){
       var view = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView");
       return{
            start: view.start,
            end: view.end
       }
  },
  success: funtion(ret){
       for(var i=0; i < ret.length; i++){
            var cell.$('td[data-date=]"' + ret[i].id + '"]');
            cell.css("background-color", "cyan");             
       }
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEventSources");
  }}]
```

And in my Controller, I have class `HOLIDAY` as:

```
public class HOLIDAY{ public string id{get; set;} }
```

and method `Holidays` as:

```
public ActionResult Holidays(DateTime start, DateTime end){
      JsonResult result  = new JsonResult();
      //Get the list of holidays 
      List<HOLIDAY> data = LoadHolidays(start, end);
      result = this.Json(data, JsonReuqestBehavior.AllowGet);
      return result;
}
```

With this approach, my applications still loads slowly when initially rendering the calendar, but runs much faster than before, especially in the case of switching the month view, which almost takes no time to color holiday cells.
Thank @ADyson again for his help.

Comment: `data: function(){
       var view = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView");
       return{
            start: view.start,
            end: view.end
       }
  },` should be redundant here - fullCalendar will append this data to the request anyway (albeit as querystring variables, rather than in the body of the POST - but looking at your controller definition you should not need a POST anyway, GET should be ok)

Comment: P.S. if you used the [events-as-a-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function) pattern for your event source, you could write your own AJAX request and, if you never make use of the `callback` to return events to fullCalendar, you can just update the cells, and there would not be any need to remove the event source afterwards. I think that's slightly less inelegant

Comment: But overall this is a creative idea, I quite like it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking each day 1 by 1 from server you can do in another way like:

1. Get all holidays with View's Model in an `array` while rendering that view.
2. Parse that `array` in a javascript array.
3. And in `dayRender` funtion check the day if that exists in that Holidays `array` if exists than its holiday otherwise not.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is good idea, but how can I get the `array` of holidays before `dayRender`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up the fullcalendar API to be sure, but you're making an Ajax call for every day in the calendar, meaning you have to wait on the network request-response every single time, 28-31 times depending on the month in view. If you can, modify that API endpoint to return a list of the holidays for a given year, or even month. Then make that call, once, before `dayRender`, and compare each date against the returned result (likely an array, so you could use `Array.includes()` for the comparison) to color the cells.

Note, I've never used fullcalendar before, I'm going off your code and the brief looki took at their API.

```js
/* Theoretically loads holidays from API endpoint */
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        global: false,
        url: "[path]/GetHolidays", /* or whatever you end up calling this endpoint */
        type: "POST", /* could also probably be a GET action */
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(val) {
            /* Now color the cells */
            $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
                dayRender: function(date, cell) {
                    if (val.includes(date) {
                        cell.css("background-color", "cyan");
                    } /* end if */
                } /* end dayRender */
            }); /* end .fullcalendar */
        } /* end success */
    }); /* end Ajax */
}); /* end $( ) */
```

Or however you want to do it, but absolutely, positively, take that Ajax call out of `dayRender`.